# Why is query_posts causing an infinite loop here?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have looked around for information explaining my issue but found none. I have a loop which supposedly should list all children categories of 'personnel'. For some reason the loop restarts infinitely. I have checked and it goes out of both the foreach and while loop but still manages to keep looping. Any ideas?

I'm calling the function here:

```
// Personnel listing
upp_loop('Personal', 'personnel-preview', '<section class="res-table">', '</section>');
```

And this is the code generating the posts:

```
// Loop through children (To make headers)
                $cats = get_categories('child_of=' . $catID . '&orderby=count&order=DESC');

                foreach ($cats as $cat) :

                $args = array(
                    'cat' => $cat->term_id
                );
                $query = new WP_query($args);

                    if ($query->have_posts()) :
                        // Echo the Category name
                        ?> <h2><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h2> <?php

                        // List all children
                        while($query->have_posts()) :
                            $query->the_post();
                                if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                    $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
                                }
                                else {
                                    $img[0] = get_template_directory_uri() . "/img/program-default.png";
                                }?>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="res-td">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $img[0] ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
                                        <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                                    </a>
                                <?php
                        endwhile;
                    endif;
                endforeach;
```

Comment: Please look at the documentation how to [query posts](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/4002/querying-posts#t=201608150832028118879). Never use `query_posts` for this...

Comment: @dingo_d I made a new WP_query object and now it doesn't get stuck on infinite. However it does the foreach 4 times. Any idea why?

Comment: Well if you have 4 categories, then it will only do `foreach` 4 times.

Comment: @dingo_d Yes of course! But I'm having 2 categories and it is showing them 2x4=8 times ;)

Comment: This looks like you're calling the function that queries your posts twice. Update your code in the question so that we can see the issue.

Comment: What is the `upp_loop()` function and where are you calling it? Also you have a typo - it's `new WP_Query($args)`, not `WP_query()`

Comment: Rubby duck debugging... I was writing what the function was doing and suddenly understood why it's doing that. It's another loop doing it. Silly mistake. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your query as variable and then call methods with it.

Make these changes in your code:
`query_posts($args)` to `$query =  query_posts($args)`
`have_posts()` to `$query->have_posts()`
`the_post()` to `$query->the_post()`

Comment: Getting error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts()